# How can you make random movement?

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing a simple pacman project on vb.net, and I've come across a great difficulty: how can I make a ghost move randomly, without seeming it is trying to move everywhere at once, which looks like it's spasming?

What I wanted was:

- To move the ghost in a random direction (up, left, right or down) and keep that direction until it hits a wall;
- When it did hit a wall, determin where it could move, and from the possibilities, choose one and keep that movement until it would hit another wall;

So basically, a loop of that. I'm guessing I definitely need a timer and a loop structure.

This is a picture of the "map":

[image: pacman design]

For example, I've tried this and it doesn't work:

```
Dim direction As movementdirection
Dim ghostlocation As Point
Dim currentLocation As Point
Dim random As New Random

Public Enum Movementdirection
    Up = 1
    Down = 2
    Left = 3
    Right = 4
End Enum

Private Sub redtimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles redtimer.Tick
    direction = DirectCast(random.Next(1, 5), Movementdirection)
    Select Case direction
        Case Movementdirection.Down
            red.Top += 2
        Case Movementdirection.Up
            red.Top -= 2
        Case Movementdirection.Left
            red.Left -= 2
        Case Movementdirection.Right
            red.Left += 2
    End Select
    direction = DirectCast(random.Next(1, 5), Movementdirection
End Sub
Public Function DetectCollection(ByVal red As PictureBox) As Boolean
    For Each wall As PictureBox In WallList
        If red.Bounds.IntersectsWith(wall.Bounds) Then
            direction = DirectCast(random.Next(1, 5), Movementdirection)
        End If
    Next
    ghostlocation = red.Location
    Return False
End Function
```

I've also tried this and didn't work that well, he also spasms.

```
Private Sub redtimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles redtimer.Tick
    Select Case direction
        Case Movementdirection.Down
            red.Top += 2
        Case Movementdirection.Up
            red.Top -= 2
        Case Movementdirection.Left
            red.Left -= 2
        Case Movementdirection.Right
            red.Left += 2
    End Select
    num = Int((4 * Rnd()) + 1)
    If num = 1 Then
        direction = Movementdirection.Down
    End If
    If num = 2 Then
        direction = Movementdirection.Left
    End If
    If num = 3 Then
        direction = Movementdirection.Right
    End If
    If num = 4 Then
    direction = Movementdirection.Up
    End If

    If Not WallList.Any(Function(wall) wall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(New Rectangle(location:=New Point(red.Location.X, (red.Location.Y + 2)), size:=red.Size))) Then
        red.Location = New Point(red.Location.X, (red.Location.Y + 2))
    Else

    End If

    If Not WallList.Any(Function(wall) wall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(New Rectangle(location:=New Point(red.Location.X, (red.Location.Y - 2)), size:=red.Size))) Then
        red.Location = New Point(red.Location.X, (red.Location.Y - 2))
    End If

    If Not WallList.Any(Function(wall) wall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(New Rectangle(location:=New Point((red.Location.X + 2), red.Location.Y), size:=red.Size))) Then
        red.Location = New Point(red.Location.X + 2, red.Location.Y)

    End If

    If Not WallList.Any(Function(wall) wall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(New Rectangle(location:=New Point(red.Location.X - 2, red.Location.Y), size:=red.Size))) Then
        red.Location = New Point((red.Location.X - 2), red.Location.Y)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `I've tried so many things and none works.` you should post some of the many things you have tried in your question, and we can help with specific issues you've encountered. If you are looking for a high level conceptual answer as to how to code the ghost movement, then I'm afraid you won't have much luck.

Comment: Thank you, I'm quite new to the site and still don't know how to make a good question. But now I put too much code, won't it be a hassle for anyone trying to help me to reach this much?

Comment: No. People need to see what you've tried and you need to clearly state what the problem is. For example, what does `has spasms` mean?

Comment: Yes, you're completely right, I'm sorry. I couldn't include a video to show, but it looked like he was trying to go to every direction at once, and wasn't moving very well at all. Thanks for your time to comment, I fail to understand I can't make vague questions like this and need to have a specific error that people can point out mistakes

Comment: This line `direction = DirectCast(random.Next(1, 5), Movementdirection)` is at the beginning of the timer, it seems like you don't want to change the direction every time the timer ticks. Only when there is collision. Right?

Comment: Right. But how do I make him move at the start, then?

Comment: Does he start from the right of the screen like shown? Then give him `Movementdirection = 3` initially. `Dim direction As movementdirection = Movementdirection.Left`

Comment: Nono, i just put him there to test. I'm going to test what you said, I'll give feedback on what happened. Thanks

Comment: He simply goes away and does not collide with any wall

Comment: Make a subroutine which is called when he is spawned which randomizes the direction, only once. The only other time it should be randomized is when it collides. Not every tick

Comment: Exactly!! I wanted to randomize the start movement just once, but I don't know really well how to do that. A subroutine? I'll look it up

Comment: Just means `Sub` but you need to call it once. Is this a form or a normal class? If it's a form you can call your Sub in Form_Load or if it's a class you can call it in the constructor. Up to you

Comment: Just an idea. Find randomly targets and then move there in a non random way.